# sqlite string replace/delete

Tags: sql, string, sqlite

I have a column in my database table with name `tags` which contains comma separated strings and it has records like this-

```
index | tags
-------------
    1 | a,b,c
    2 | b
    3 | c
    4 | z
    5 | b,a,c
    6 | p,f,w
    7 | a,c,b
```

**(for simplicity i am denoting strings with characters)**

Now i want to replace/delete particular string.

**Delete -** say I want to delete `b` from all rows. If `tags` column become empty after this operation that row/record should be deleted (index 2 in this case). My records should look like this after this operation.

```
index | tags
-------------
    1 | a,c
    3 | c
    4 | z
    5 | a,c
    6 | p,f,w
    7 | a,c
```

**Replace -** say I want to replace all `a` with `k` on original records

```
index | tags
-------------
    1 | k,b,c
    2 | b
    3 | c
    4 | z
    5 | b,k,c
    6 | p,f,w
    7 | k,c,b
```

**Question -** I am thinking of using `replace` function somehow but not sure how to meet above requirement with that. Can i do this in a single sql command? If not please suggest best way to do this (may be multiple sql commands).

Comment: Why don't you store the tags one per row in a separate table?

Comment: @CL. I have other complex operations on these records which is much simplified in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use MSSQL, I'm not sure sqlite. But, you use `REPLACE` function, like this:

To remove `b`:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET tags = REPLACE(REPLACE(tags, ',b', ' '), 'b,', ' ')
UPDATE Your_Table
SET tags = NULL WHERE tags = 'b'
```

To replace `a` with `k`:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET tags = REPLACE(tags, 'a', 'k')
```

Comment: This will also replace substrings, and does not handle commas correctly.

Comment: I replace `'b,'` or `',b'` or `'b'`

Comment: Your query will replace `'a,bc'` with `'ac'`.

Comment: @CL. You are correct but in my case string contains combination of alphabetic and numeric characters only. So it should work for me.